# In flüssigem oder im flüssigen?

Tags: dative, definite-article

Was ist hier der Unterschied? Was ist richtig? Oder beides (unterschiedliche Bedeutung)?

1. Es fließt i**n** flüssige**m** Zustand.
2. Es fließt i**m** flüssige**n** Zustand.

Oder ähnlich

1. Sie tanzt i**n** grüne**m** Kleid.
2. Sie tanzt i**m** grüne**n** Kleid.

Comment: `Es ist grün in flüssigem Zustand` wäre nicht so tautologisch.

Answer (score 10):

Im ersten Fall ist das Substantiv bestimmt, im zweiten Fall unbestimmt:

> Sie tanzt in grünem Kleid. **≈** Sie tanzt in einem grünen Kleid.
>   Sie tanzt im grünen Kleid. **≈** Sie tanzt in dem grünen Kleid.

Das Auslassen (bzw. Zusammenziehen) des Artikels (*einem* bzw. *den*) ist in beiden Fällen zwar möglich, aber in diesem Beispiel ungewöhnlich.

Der tautologische Beispielsatz mit dem flüssigen Zustand ist etwas ungünstig um Unterschiede zu erläutern, deswegen User Unknowns Beispiel:

> Es ist grün in flüssigem Zustand. **≈** Es ist grün und (außerdem) in einem flüssigen Zustand.
>   Es ist grün im flüssigen Zustand. **≈** Es ist in dem flüssigen Zustand grün. **≈** Wenn es im flüssigen Zustand ist, ist es grün.

Im ersten Fall impliziert die Verwendung von *in (einem) flüssigen Zustand* (statt *im flüssigen Zustand* oder schlicht *flüssig*), dass es mehrere flüssige Zustände gibt. Im letzten Fall ist das Zusammenziehen des Artikels normal.

Comment: Na ja, _dem_ wird ja nicht ausgelassen, sondern mit dem _in_ zu _im_ zusammengezogen. – _In flüssigem Zustand_ finde ich ganz OK, weil es ja im allgemeinen nicht mehrere unterschiedliche flüssige Zustände gibt.

Comment: @chirlu: Stimmt; dass es einmal eine Zusammenziehung ist, habe ich übersehen. *In flüssigem Zustand* kann in der Tat normal sein, aber der Beispielsatz war eh nicht normal.

Comment: Danke sehr. Mein Beispiel war also schlecht. Was wäre also bei diesem korrigierten Beispiel „korrekt“: _Flüssigstickstoff ist Stickstoff in flüssigem Aggregatzustand._ Oder besser _im flüssigen_? Ich würde ersteres bevorzugen.

Comment: Ich würde zweiteres klar bevorzugen. Ersteres wird zwar vermutlich auch richtig verstanden werden, aber impliziert auch, dass es mehrere flüssige Aggregatszustände gibt (was zwar nicht ganz falsch ist, aber hier wohl kaum gemeint ist). (Alles unter der Annahme, dass Du jemandem unmissverständlich erklären möchtest, was Flüssigstickstoff ist – sonst ist das Beispiel wieder ziemlich redundant.)